# Enabling EF code first migrations V 4.3.1.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have worked with other migration projects and had no problem.  in my current project i seperated the migration and model projects.  I get the following error when adding migration or even when enabling migration (the configuration class is created):

> PM> enable-migrations -Force No classes deriving from DbContext found
>   in the current project. Edit the generated Configuration class to
>   specify the context to enable migrations for.
>   System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or
>   more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property
>   for more information.    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.<.ctor>b_*1(Assembly
>   a)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.d*_14`2.MoveNext()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index,
>   IEnumerable`1 collection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper..ctor(MappingContext
>   mappingContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.MapTypes(EdmModel model)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_CodeFirstModel()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext
>   context, XmlWriter writer)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(XmlWriter
>   w)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1
>   writeXml)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration, DbContext usersContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   migrationsConfiguration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.RunCore()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>   Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Thanks

Comment: Have you selected the project containing the DbContext in the dropdown in the package manager?

Comment: yes,I did. still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message says that you have no class deriving from DbContext which means that you need to define one.

Something like this:

```
class MyContext: DbContext
{
   public DBSet<Some_Entity_Which_Represent_DB_table> SetName {get;set;}

   public MyContext() : base(here you can specify database with its name or connectionString or leave it empty)
   {}
}
```